# Using Firebase CLI, generate UID for new users imported using firebase:import?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I am importing a CSV file of users for a client from their old system. I am provided with an email address and name and have managed to successfully import a group of users by manually specifying UIDs of '1', '2', '3', '4', etc. (obviously not resembling the Firebase UID at all).

Will this present problems later on? Is there a way to auto-generate UIDs using the Firebase CLI when importing this list of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIDs just need to be unique. It's up to you to do that any way you want. The CLI will not do this for you. There are a lot of ways to generate unique strings, so use any method that suits you best.

You will have problems with sequential numbers if you try to import more users and you don't know which number is the next one in the sequence, so it's probably better to generate long unique strings that are highly unlikely to collide, such as UUIDs.

Comment: Thank you for this answer @Doug. Do you know a method for doing that in my spreadsheet automatically? I have about 200 users so can't do it manually

Comment: You might want to ask a new question specifically targeted about whatever spreadsheet software you're using, with this specific task at hand.

Comment: @Garrison, https://guidgenerator.com/